# runtime.onMessage not receiving message

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build my first chrome extension and finding hard time to send message from popup.js to work.js. Any help is highly appreciated.

Popup.js script

```
var but = document.getElementById('ok_btn');

if (but )
{
    but.addEventListener("click", saveChanges , false);
}
function saveChanges() {
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    alert(username);
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ website: username, 
    message:"Username_Received"});

    chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: 'work.js'});
    window.close();
}
```

Work.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse){
    console.log('reached');
    alert('inside message request');
    if(request.website == "Username_Received"){
       alert(request.website);
    }
});
```